# How to pass ExpressJS locals variable to an EJS template and use it as parameter for calling a JS function from onload HTML event

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

```
const hostname = "192.168.8.154";
const port = 3002;

app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {

    db.collection('sys_params').find().toArray()
    .then(sysParams => {
        //console.log(sysParams);
        app.locals.sysParams = sysParams;
        app.locals.ipAddress = hostname;
        app.locals.portNo = port;
        app.locals.url = hostname + ':' + port;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
    next()

})
```

Here where I need to replace the hard coded IP Address and Port with app.locals.url coming from ExpressJS using EJS HTML tagging.

```
  <body onload="landingPage('192.168.8.154:3002')">
```

To be used as

```
  <body onload="landingPage(<% url%>)">
```

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

              function landingPage(ipAddress){
                // Random Desktop image on-load 
                let loginDesktopArr = ["1-Sunday.jpg", "2-Monday.jpg", "3-Tuesday.jpg", "4-Wedsday.jpg", "5-Thursday.jpg", "6-Friday.jpg", "7-Saturday.jpg"];
                let loginDesktopImg = loginDesktopArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * loginDesktopArr.length)];
                let loginDesktopUrl = "'http://"+ipAddress+"/img/" + loginDesktopImg + "'";
                document.getElementById('header').style = "background-image: url(" + loginDesktopUrl + ");";
              }

            </script>
```

Using the EJS tags within the call to JS function and I get the expected error url is not defined.

```
    25|     <title><%= __('LandingPageTabTitle') %></title>
    26|   </head>
 >> 27|   <body onload="landingPage(<% url%>)">
    28|   
    29|          <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    30|          

url is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap url with single quotes

```
<body onload="landingPage('<%= url%>')">
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, same error message returned after wrapping the url locals variable - url is not defined

Comment: also use this (<%=) to evaluate the value which will be passed into the function,
here is working demo

[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/express-simple-khikyx?file=index.js,views%2Findex.ejs)